# What is the meaning of "crinkly eyes"?

Tags: meaning

It is the part of the book I was reading:

> Mr. Dawes, the friendly young man from the local real estate office, stopped near the front walk and turned around.
>
> "Everything okay?" he asked, staring first at Josh, then at me, with his crinkly blue eyes.

But I don't understand the meaning of "crinkly eyes" . When we say someone's eyes are crinkly?

Comment: Did you look up [the meaning of **crinkly**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/crinkly)?

Comment: ...or do a [basic image search?](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=crinkly+eyes&ia=images&iax=images) A picture is worth a thousand words, after all.

Comment: @stangdon "used to say something is covered in many small lines and folds" I don't understand how it can be relevant to eyes.

Comment: Think of crinkled or crinkly paper, and then imagine those crinkles, or little lines, around the eyes.

Comment: "Crinkly eyes" is a form of descriptive writing, this ability with writing or prose to evoke in the reader what was seen, felt, tested, smelled, or heard.  Eyes don't crinkle. They're a fluid filled ball. A writer is given great latitude to use descriptive writing to help you envision a synonym of crinkle [babbled, gurgled, murmured, sighed; whispered] Ref Merriam-Webster dict. - in one way: as if a person just got up/eyes full of crud. Other, in context: as posts herein. Squinty, kind of wrinkly eyelids. You may have to return to the original text to put descriptive writing in context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's "crinkly" isn't the actual ***eyes*** - it's the ***skin around the eyes***.

Note that ***crinkly*** here is evocative of ["laughter lines"](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/what-are-these-lines-in-your-face-called-in-english.2038011/) (it's a ***positive*** description). That's as opposed to near-synonymous ***wrinkly***, which is evocative of deteriorating / saggy / lined skin from old age and/or constant bad-tempered scowling / frowning.

So *with his crinkly blue<sup>1</sup> eyes* here equates to ***with a smile***, with the additional implication that Dawes is a good-natured man who *habitually* smiles (so those lines are "engraved" in his face).

---

<sup>1</sup> Also note the extremely positive associations of this *particular* eye colour, as reflected in the informal idiomatic British English usage [***blue-eyed boy***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blue-eyed-boy) - *a boy or man who is liked very much and is treated well by someone, especially by someone in authority*.